# AndroidManifest.xml For Different Flavors

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-flavors

I am having issues with a paid flavor of my app. The only difference between the paid and the free app, is the free has ads.
Everytime I upload the paid bundle to the play store, I get a warning that my app has an advertising id but I am declaring no ads.
I have a main, free, and paid manifest.
How do I make it so that the paid manifest doesn't include any of the ad code ?.

Right now the free manifest ad code is tagged with tools:node="remove" for the permissions.
I thought that is what excluded it from the paid manifest.
Somehow I am missing something with how these manifests should be separated.
I just want the free manifest to be included in the free app and then the paid manifest in the paid version.
How do I do this ?

Comment: Have you checked what is included in the end in the APK files you build? What are the relevant lines you have in your Manifest files?